# Converting EPOCH time stamps to date

Tags: python, unix, timestamp, epoch

I have the sensor gyroscope data that is to be analysed along with the epoch time stamps. I want to analyse the time stamps as HH-MM-SS format. So, while I am trying to convert the time stamps, the resulting time is not correct. below are the values for consideration.

```
| Time            | Gyro_X       | Gyro_Y      | Gyro_Z        |
|-----------------|--------------|-------------|---------------|
| 112802627681000 | 0.09686792   | 0.14810029  | 0.005777027   |
| 112802636065000 | 0.029674599  | 0.10087131  | 2.1168962E-5  |
| 112802636868000 | 0.029674599  | 0.10087131  | 2.1168962E-5  |
| 112802645721000 | -0.019805614 | 0.028886953 | -0.007304834  |
| 112802646541000 | -0.019805614 | 0.028886953 | -0.007304834  |
| 112802655003000 | -0.030801188 | -0.0493038, | -0.0048613725 |
| 112802656170000 | -0.030801188 | -0.0493038  | -0.0048613725 |
```

The correct time must be 20 july 2014 16-20-31 GMT. I am using python to convert the timestamps with the help of the time library.

```
import time
y=time.strftime('%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S',  time.gmtime(112802646541000/1000000))
```

To add to my question the sensor data is being recorded using cellbots data logger app. The timestamps are recorded using Sensorevent.Timestamp. So,I wanted to know does the timestamp have something to do with this  method.

Comment: How are you sure that's the correct time?  I get this as 29 Sep 2005.

Comment: What do you know about the timestamps?  For example, are they microseconds relative to a GPS epoch?  Or are they a different unit, or different epoch?  Without that information (or two distinct values and there corresponding UTC times), everything is just guesswork.

Answer (score 1):

Dividing by 10**6 as you are doing gives 29 Jul 1973. Dividing instead by 10**5 gives 29 Sep 2005. If they should be representing 20 Jul 2014 then it doesn't look like these numbers are based on a 1 Jan 1970 epoch.

Answer (score 1):

I think a clue to this puzzle lies in

```sh
$ date -u -d "@$((112802627681000 / 65536))"
Wed 17 Jul 15:51:41 UTC 2024
```

So it looks like your timestamps are fixed-point (48.16) seconds since 1960-01-01.

You probably need to use:

```
datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(s/65536 - 315619200)
```

I got that last magic number by calculating the number of seconds between 1960-01-01 and 1970-01-01:

```sh
$ date -u -d 1960-01-01 +%s
-315619200
```

Comment: There's still a slight discrepancy: that gives `17 July 2014 16:51:41`.  Can anybody account for those three days, and complete this answer?

Answer (score -1):

```
import pytz, datetime
s = 112802646541000/1000000
print(datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(s).strftime('%d %B %Y %H:%M:%S'))
```

Comment: While this code snippet may solve the question, including an explanation [really helps](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now!  Please [edit] your answer to add explanation, and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Comment: Also, that code gives 29 July 1973.  Dividing by 100000 instead gives 29 September 2005, which is closer, but still no cigar.